# libgraph-1.0.2 makefile

Tags: make

I have installed guile2.0 into /usr/dev

two makefiles (Makefile.am and Makefile.in) along with executable makefile exist in libgraph-1.0.2 after extracting and running ./configure.
command ./configure doesn't appear to have any errors.

make results in error at line 34 "missing separator" code is if(GUILE)
changing to if"tab"(GUILE) or if"tab"("tab"GUILE) yields same error
if I change to "tab"if(GUILE) I get "recipe commences before first target".

I have tried every combination of  I can think of but I always get one of the two errors and make fails.

Could someone advise a newbie on what needs to be done?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what was wrong with simple `sudo apt-get install guile-2.0` (it [is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=guile-2.0)).

Comment: nothing at all..My first line says I installed guile-2.0 and is in /usr/dev

Comment: What do you mean by *libgraph-1.0.2*? From where did you downloaded it?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Perhaps I have not been clear. I want to code (draw) simple graphic shapes in Ubuntu 18.04 using g++. However, every example I've seen uses "graphics.h" which is not included with g++. Libgraph does include"graphics,h" but so far I have been stymied trying to install libgraph.

Comment: Could you please share a link to example, which uses "graphics.h"?

Comment: As a neophyte I look at the code from the examples on this website "https://cplusplus.happycodings.com/computer-graphics/" The following website is one of many I have perused on how to install graphics.h https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-graphics-h-c-library-gcc-compiler-linux/

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 - sorry for the delay but although I answered yesterday I don't see the result here.

Answer (score 0):

To get more reproducible results consider to remove your self-installed `guile2.0` from `/usr/dev`.

The `libgraph` library is a bit out-dated. It currently exists only in two repositories: [YACP and ArchLinux](https://repology.org/project/libgraph/versions).

The [PKGBUILD script from ArchLinux AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=libgraph) shows that it needs old `guile-1.8` package, but it exists only in previous Ubuntu 16.04 LTS release.

Then at first we need to add this *xenial* repository to the system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe"
```

and install the packages with build tools and dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-1.8-dev
```

Then download and install `libgraph`:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/libgraph/libgraph-1.0.2.tar.gz
tar -xf libgraph-1.0.2.tar.gz
cd libgraph-1.0.2
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libgraph.* /usr/lib
```

and finally build simple `circle.c` example from [the article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-graphics-h-c-library-gcc-compiler-linux/)

```
// C code to illustrate using 
// graphics in linux enviornment 
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<graphics.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int gd = DETECT, gm; 
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, NULL); 
  
    circle(50, 50, 30); 
  
    delay(500000); 
    closegraph(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

with `gcc circle.c -o circle -lgraph` and run it with `./circle` .

Comment: thanks for the help I have found what was actually wrong. I needed to add -lglut etc, etc to my makefile. I have both graphics.h and OpenGL working now.