# Installing libgraph: make error

Tags: 20.04, make

so I'm trying to install libgraph.

Running `./configure` seemed fine, but I'm also appending its output just in case.
After running `make` I got an output, that's a bit similar to this guy's ([trying to install libgraph](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942863/trying-to-install-libgraph)), but much longer with much more warnings.

`./config` output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vp3KK2WxQV/

`make` output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wQc6FMK5HB/

In previously mentioned question, they asked for output of `make V=1`, so I'll put it here also, just in case.

`make V=1` output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WhWRz7vYRh/

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/a/1145105/66509 .

Comment: @N0rbert I did and the `make` output is now this: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YnfGrz8H7q/

Comment: In order to compile "libgraph" you have to install these packages first : ```sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-1.8 guile-1.8-dev libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev libesd0-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev```  as stated [here](https://seitcg.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-install-libgraph-on-ubuntu.html) . The output of make indicates that you have missing libraries in your system.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi It looks like I have all of them installed already

Comment: @Dave_5999 Simply follow my recommended above answer. I have just checked and can confirm that it works on 20.04 LTS system.

Comment: @N0rbert I did it all exactly the same except removing `guile2.0` from `/usr/dev` folder (I don't have `/dev` folder inside the `/usr` folder, only separately `/usr` and `/dev` in none of which is any `guile` file)